# pandas to_html: add attributes to table tag

Tags: python, html, pandas

I'm using the pandas [to_html()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) method to build a table for my website. I want to add some attributes to the `<table>` tag; however I'm not sure how to do this.

```
my_table = Markup(df.to_html(classes="table"))
```

Which produces:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe table">
```

I want to produce the following:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe table" attribute="value" attribute2="value2">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be achieved simply by manipulating the rendered html with a simple regular expression:

```
import re

df = pd.DataFrame(1, index=[1, 2], columns=list('AB'))

html = df.to_html(classes="table")
html = re.sub(
    r'<table([^>]*)>',
    r'<table\1 attribute="value" attribute2="value2">',
    html
)

print(html.split('\n')[0])

<table border="1" class="dataframe table" attribute="value" attribute2="value2">
```

Answer (score 1):

For a pandas-only solution, you can use a `Styler` object:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(1, index=[1, 2], columns=list('AB'))
styled = df.style.set_table_attributes('foo="foo" bar="bar"')
print(styled.to_html())
```

Output:

```html
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<table id="T_7d7d8" foo="foo" bar="bar">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="blank level0" >&nbsp;</th>
      <th id="T_7d7d8_level0_col0" class="col_heading level0 col0" >A</th>
      <th id="T_7d7d8_level0_col1" class="col_heading level0 col1" >B</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th id="T_7d7d8_level0_row0" class="row_heading level0 row0" >1</th>
      <td id="T_7d7d8_row0_col0" class="data row0 col0" >1</td>
      <td id="T_7d7d8_row0_col1" class="data row0 col1" >1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th id="T_7d7d8_level0_row1" class="row_heading level0 row1" >2</th>
      <td id="T_7d7d8_row1_col0" class="data row1 col0" >1</td>
      <td id="T_7d7d8_row1_col1" class="data row1 col1" >1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```